# add foreign key support for RoR 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

im using migration files to create the database tables but i want to set up foreign keys too.

is there any good gem for this? i cant find gems for 3.0.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using [foreigner](http://github.com/matthuhiggins/foreigner). It works with Rails 3 and it has a very simple API to create foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [foreign_keys](http://github.com/perfectline/foreign_keys)

Comment: i think that one doesnt support rails 3.

Comment: I'm not sure... I should try that out probably, as I am the author :P
I will do it ASAP.